# Why Spring HATEOAS returns duplicate links causing JSON deserialization exception?

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-hateoas, hal

Vanilla entity User -

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 262950482349139355L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, unique = false)
    @Convert(converter = NameConverter.class)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false, unique = false)
    @Convert(converter = NameConverter.class)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUM", nullable = false, unique = false)
    @Convert(converter = PhoneNumberConverter.class)
    private String phoneNum;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = true, unique = false)
    @Convert(converter = OptionalStringConverter.class)
    private Optional<String> email;
}
```

Search result with hostname changed in the URL - 2 _links present

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://hostname/users/search/findByLastName?lastName=doe{&page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "firstName" : "John",
      "lastName" : "Doe",
      "phoneNum" : "111-111-1111",
      "email" : null,
      "_links" : { },
      "_embedded" : { },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://hostname/users/1",
          "templated" : false
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

**Edit**:

The duplicate links are not present when the resource is accessed on it's own. However, when a client (a microservice in my case) makes a request using a `RestTemplate`, the response comes back with 2 `_links` as shown above.

```
@Override
public Collection<Long> getUserIdsByFirstName(String firstName) {
    String findByFirstNameUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(userServiceUrl)
        .path("/users/search/findByFirstName").queryParam("firstName", firstName).toUriString();

// This is where ResponseEntity.body would have the 2 _links, if ResponseEntity<String> were used. I used a custom object to weed that out.
ResponseEntity<UserSearchResult> userSearchResult = restTemplate.exchange(findByFirstNameUri, GET, dummyEntity,
        UserSearchResult.class);
     ...
}
```

I'm using Spring Data JPA, Spring Data Rest, Spring HATEOAS and Spring Cloud. Here's a [link to the project](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/java-ee/tree/master/salon-appointment-system/user-service) on my Github.

Full disclosure: I've filed an issue on Spring HATEOAS Github.

Comment: Please show us your code where you assemble the resource. The entity and the expected result is not enough. We do a very similar thing in our own software and it works.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig I don't assemble the resource. I'm using Spring JPA to do that for me. I've updated my post clarifying that and a link to the code.

Comment: I don't want to brows through your GitHub repo to fix your things. Please post the relevant code. The entity and the result is not relevant in this case. And if I would browse your repo - just theoretically - I would say that you assemble your resource in your controller with a `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`. But before you do that you put links manually to the `UserSearchResult `. So yes, you assemble the resource and you do it wrong. So show that code.

Comment: Hypothetically, if I were assembling the `User` resource, I'd have been glad to show the code. Whether or not you want to look at the link, that's up to you. Just to be clear, I never asked you to "fix" anything for me, but the mere fact of responding on an open forum implies a willingness to help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The forum rules say "post the code, not just links"! (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I ask you to do that and explained you that the code you showed is is not enough, but you still don't do it. And if you didn't get the irony in my comment (it's strong!): I looked at your GitHub repo and named the exact classes where your problem is. Have you even checked this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using spring-data-rest not just spring-hateoas. So you have no resource and no controllers. I think this was the major misconception here.

I think you got something wrong with your custom repository.

I would change two things:

- remove @Repository from UserRepositoryCustomImpl
- make UserRepository extend UserRepositoryCustom

so

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom
```

and

```
public class UserRepositoryCustomImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom
```

This is what you need to to in order to implement custom repository methods:

see also http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: I don't use the `UserRepositoryCustom`, I toyed with the idea initially but didn't end up using it. `UserRepository` just extends `JpaRepository`
`public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {...}`

Comment: I confirm that `UserRepositoryCustom` is unrelated to this issue (by deleting `UserRepositoryCustom`). I've added more info to my post.